# Why did Java chose Xmx and Xms naming convention for heap sizes?

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-size

As per online description following are properties used in Java linked with Sizes:

> Use -Xmx to specify the maximum heap size
>
> Use -Xms to specify the initial Java heap size
>
> Use -Xss to set the Java thread stack size

What is meaning of mx and ms? Does mx means maximum and ms means what?

Comment: How is this opnion based question as i can see closed request? Is not anything official related to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `ms = minimum heap size / heap memory start size` and `mx = maximum heap size`.

Comment: The question is "what do the letters mx and ms stand for?", not "what do these options do?"

Comment: `m` = memory / `x` = maximal memory, `s`= starting memory

Comment: Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca and Joop Eggen, I've edited my answer to be more succinct and include your definition as well.

Comment: @0xadecimal I'm still not sure this answers the question. For example, why should "x" stand for "maximum"?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Yes i also have same confusion is X alone maximum or "mx" collectively stands for Maximum?